# In one line I need to change the font type and also underline the font

Tags: vb.net

This is the code I tried but does not work . .

```
Dim lab As New Label
lab.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Courier New", 8.25!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Underline, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, 0)
```

Comment: _8.25f_ to pass a float constant use !

Comment: Steve - that makes no difference it still does not underline !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it does work. Did you add it to a form? Use `Form.Controls.Add(Control)`

[image]

You said "In one line", so...

```
Me.Controls.Add(New Label With {.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Courier New", 8.25!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Underline, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, 0), .Location = New Point(10, 10), .Text = "abcDEF"})
```

but here it is a bit more readable

```
Dim lab As New Label()
lab.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Courier New", 8.25!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Underline, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, 0)
lab.Location = New Point(10, 10)
lab.Text = "abcDEF"
Me.Controls.Add(lab)
```

Comment: Using your readable code I get no underlined characters for the control - The only thing missing in my code is this instruction "Use Form.Controls.Add(Control)" where do i put this in my form?

Comment: If  I just use the following line : lab.Font = New Font(lab.Font, FontStyle.Underline)

then it underlines but does not use my font :(

Comment: @BASitBulbulia you create a new label and it must be placed on a form and since you can see it then I guess that is being done. So my answer doesn't solve your problem and it seems to be something else.

Comment: I just changed the font to "Consolas" and it worked perfectly - THIS IS STRANGE !!!